# How to translate in 2 languages "a section title" in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am beginner in Angular, when the user clicks in a french page. I would like to display `My Homepage`  in french.

[image]

My code in the page -> **navigation.service.ts** seems to be correct.

```
defaultMenu: IMenuItem[] = [
    {   
     name: 'My Project', idI18N: '2491',
     description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
     type: 'dropDown',
     icon: 'i-University',
     sub: [
     { icon: 'i-', idI18N: '2491', name: 'My Homepage', state: '/dashboard/homepage', type: 'link', onlyAgents: false, onlyTRX: false },
     { icon: 'i-', idI18N: '2492', name: 'Customers for a stock', state: '/dashboard/stocksClients', type: 'link', onlyAgents: true, onlyTRX: false },                   
            ...
           
        ]
    },
```

Ok, for the page -> **admin-layout-sidebar-compact.component.html**

```
   <div id="breadcrumb">
        <div class="wrapper">
             <ul style="padding-left: 0px;">
                  <li class="first">{{mainSection}} /</li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{{subSection}}"><!-- sectionTitle --> - {{subSection}}</a>
                  </li>
                            
                 </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
```

I think the problem is on the page -> **admin-layout-sidebar-compact.component.ts**

I don't understand the lines on the subSection...
I think the code is not completed? How do I get ts to interact with my fr.json file?

```
getSelectedItem() {
      if (window && window.location) {
        const activeRoute = window.location.hash || window.location.pathname;
        this.nav.forEach(item => {
          item.active = false;
          if (item.sub) {
            item.sub.forEach(subItem => {
              subItem.active = false;
              if(activeRoute.indexOf(subItem.state) !== -1){
                this.mainSection = item.name;
                this.subSection = subItem.name;
                //console.log(subItem);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Here is an idea of the file -> **admin-layout-sidebar-compact.component.ts** if necessary...

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../../../services/navigation.service';
import { SearchService } from 'src/app/shared/services/search.service';
import { SharedAnimations } from 'src/app/shared/animations/shared-animations';
import { Router, RouteConfigLoadStart, ResolveStart, RouteConfigLoadEnd, ResolveEnd } from '@angular/router';
import {
  IMenuItem,
  IChildItem
} from "../../../services/navigation.service";

//
//  Share the current secondTitle
//


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-layout-sidebar-compact',
  templateUrl: './admin-layout-sidebar-compact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-layout-sidebar-compact.component.scss']
})
export class AdminLayoutSidebarCompactComponent implements OnInit {
    moduleLoading: boolean;
    selectedItem: IMenuItem;
    nav: IMenuItem[];
    mainSection;
    subSection;
  
    constructor(
      public navService: NavigationService,
      public searchService: SearchService,
      private router: Router
    ) { 
        this.navService.menuItems$.subscribe(items => {
          this.nav = items;
          this.getSelectedItem()
        });
    }
  
    ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart || event instanceof ResolveStart) {
          this.moduleLoading = true;
        }
        if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd || event instanceof ResolveEnd) {
          this.moduleLoading = false;
        }
      });

      // Get main section and title from from menu ?
      this.launch();
      
    }

    launch(){
      this.getSelectedItem();
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.launch();
      }, 2000);
    }

    getSelectedItem() {
      if (window && window.location) {
        const activeRoute = window.location.hash || window.location.pathname;
        this.nav.forEach(item => {
          item.active = false;
          if (item.sub) {
            item.sub.forEach(subItem => {
              subItem.active = false;
              if(activeRoute.indexOf(subItem.state) !== -1){
                this.mainSection = item.name;
                this.subSection = subItem.name;
                //console.log(subItem);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand anything, many thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: You should use NgxTranslate. This [link](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate) will help

Comment: @DRASHTI DOBARIYA: Thank you  DRASHTI DOBARIYA I see this. ^^